# Run Artifactory as Docker container response 404

Tags: docker, http-status-code-404, artifactory

I created docker container with this command:

```
docker run --name artifactory -d -p 8081:8081 \
   -v /jfrog/artifactory:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory \
   -e EXTRA_JAVA_OPTIONS='-Xms128M -Xmx512M -Xss256k -XX:+UseG1GC' \
   docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:latest
```

and started artifactory, but the response I get is 404 - not found

[image]

If u access http://99.79.191.172:8081/artifactory u see it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you follow the [Artifactory Docker install](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Installing+Artifactory#InstallingArtifactory-DockerInstallation) documentation, you'll see you also need to expose port 8082 for the new JFrog Router, which is now handling the traffic coming in to the UI (and other services as needed).

This new architecture is from Artifactory 7.x. By setting `latest` as the repository tag, you don't have full control of what version you are running...

So your command should look like

```
docker run --name artifactory -p 8081:8081 -d -p 8082:8082 \
    -v /jfrog/artifactory:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory \
    docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:latest
```

For controlling the configuration (like the Java options you want), it's recommended to use the [Artifactory system.yaml configuration](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Installing+Artifactory#InstallingArtifactory-ProductConfiguration). This file is the best way to control all aspects of the Artifactory system configuration.

Comment: also see : https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Installing+Artifactory#InstallingArtifactory-DockerInstallation

Comment: @Eldad Assis
Please see me additional question